# Host wp-content on other domain, much like a CDN

Tags: content, cdn

Would it be possible to host wp-content on another domain, so that all the uploads and images would go and load from there?
If so, how would I go about configuring wordpress to do this, preferably without using a third-party plugin?

Comment: Your question as it is now (1. Jun. 2012, 6:00 UTC) doesn’t say anything about another server, so the answer by Aahan Krish is correct. If you want use a real CDN you should use [our search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=cdn). Next time [prepare your question better](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask). Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Comment: True, I wasn't very clear at all; that by other domain I meant other domain that also was on another server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In **WordPress Dashboard > Settings > Media** and fill the field "Full URL path to files" with your *other domain*. See the screenshot below:

[image: Media Settings]

**EDIT:** I thought it would be obvious, but it isn't. Here's what you exactly need to do:

1. You should map your domain to point to:

   1. **public_html** directory, IF it's also your WordPress installation's root directory.
   2. **public_html/subdirectory/** directory, IF your WordPress installation is in its own subdirectory.
   3. If you have a custom path set in "Store uploads in folder", then your domain should point to the directory ABOVE the custom uploads directory.

      For instance, lets consider this is how your settings are:

      **`Store uploads in this folder:`**`media/uploads/`
      (implies **public_html/media/uploads/** directory -- which is, as you guessed it, outside your WordPress installation directory)

      **`Full URL path to files:`**`http://newdomain.com`

      Then, you should make sure, http://newdomain.com points to **public_html/media/uploads/** directory.
2. Now, add the domain (or sub-domain) in the field shown in the screenshot above. Simply adding the domain, without mapping it to your WP installation, won't do the job.

If you don't know how to point your domain, it's a totally different question, and is out of the scope of [Wordpress.StackExchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/). Google it, you should definitely get your answers. :)

---

And as for hosting your images on a different server and different domain, you have no better choice than [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/) <-- yes, a caching plugin for WordPress.

Comment: Great! thank you. If I were to use a web service such as Amazon's cloudfront, how would the method differ?

Comment: @messerschmidt Ah... it's a completely different story. You'd have to use a plugin for that -- the best one I know is a caching plugin that does that > [W3 Total Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/w3-total-cache/)

Comment: Cheers! I thought as much. The above method should be sufficient for me, but I'm curious to try a CDN in the future

Comment: Images still will be uploaded to the same domain where wp is. _edited by toscho_

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate. Would you know how one would go about doing what I asked in the original post?

Comment: This answer would work if you manually reupload/clone wp upload dir to the server in that field. so it would work. If you are the only one who creates stuff in website -it's good to go, if not-it's wrong :) Or you can set up BackWpUp plugin to every hour backup that dir to your remote server :D – _edited by toscho_

Comment: The thing is, I don't really want any files uploaded to the server where the installation is

Comment: it's impossible. Or you have to rewrite WP upload forms to post to other server, and bunch of other authentification and so on stuff. well maybe someone will do this for 300$

Comment: @messerschmidt See my edit.

Comment: @Tommix Stay polite or stay away. _Please._

Comment: @toscho don't understand where i'm not polite, but you definatly not seen me when i'm beeing not polite than :D Because this dude writes nonsense. Asker wants to use DIFERENT server and this guys teahes how to store files in THE SAME server but get them via other domain. but the fact is this: files still will be loaded from the same server.

Comment: @Tommix The question is about a different domain, not a different server. Even if your interpretation were correct there would be _no_ excuse for derogatory comments.

Answer (score 1):

**My second aswer**:

to use other server it's not easy, to use your subdomain, lets say media.domain.com it's not hard, once i used it in my price compare site done with WP. The main sthing to speed up loadin times is to use diferent domains, and subdomains is good to, cause browsers will open new connection for them too. So use this tutorial: http://www.computingunleashed.com/host-images-in-sub-domain.html

Server will be the same, bat browser will create new connection to load images, so loading times will be shorter (if server is not slow).

Comment: Thanks! But I'm really looking to host the files on a completely different location, due to various reasons. I gather this is difficult, but still possible?

Comment: Well everything is possible, but i don't know answer. it's hard, cause file uploading is LOCAL stuff, and there have to be a lot of modifications to reupload files to remote server.

Comment: That's unfortunate... I had hope you'd be able to use something like mod_rewrite to change the location of the wp-content directory.

Answer (score -2):

Paste this to your .HTACCESS file:

```
Header unset ETag
FileETag None

# BEGIN Expire headers  
<ifModule mod_expires.c>  
    ExpiresActive On  
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 35 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"  
    ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"  
</ifModule>  
# END Expire headers  

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers  
<ifModule mod_headers.c>  
    <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">  
        Header set Cache-Control "public"  
    </filesMatch>  
    <filesMatch "\.(css)$">  
        Header set Cache-Control "public"  
    </filesMatch>  
    <filesMatch "\.(js)$">  
        Header set Cache-Control "private"  
    </filesMatch>  
    <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">  
        Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"  
    </filesMatch>  
</ifModule>  
# END Cache-Control Headers
```

This will tell browser to cache all javascript, images, css to computer, so images won't be downloaded from you until they changes.
You can use Best browser- chrome to test it with ctrl+shift+j in timeline you can actually see how much time took to download images, the cached ones usually takes 25 ms (cause server first have to say: files is not changed so use the local copy :) )

Comment: This is all good, but how would I go about configuring wordpress so that it will upload the files to the second domain, and then also read from it?